# Develop files and Production files for each branch

Tags: build, branch

I have a structure directory like:

- src => contains all files to develop the app (gulpfile, components, etc.).
- build => contains all final files like *`styles/styles.css`*, *`js/app.js`*, `index.html etc`., compressed, minified, to deploy on server.

How could handle/ignore files on each branch, like:

- master branch => **all files**/directories (src, build, etc.).
- production branch => **only build directory to deploy on server**.

I tried with .gitignore, but I have a conflict with the .gitignore files when merge branches.
I tried editing config file inside .git directory, but nothing happens.

BTW, my project not includes nodejs.

It's possible do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general what you are trying to do isn't a best practice. To really do what you want you would have a different git repository for your build artifacts.

A better approach is to have a CI server that builds the branch and archives the results somewhere. Usually you would have your build zip it up and store it somewhere you know it is immutable.

Alternatively you could commit your build artifacts but change your deployment scripts to only deploy the build directory.